# Using youtube-dl to extract both mp3 file and the file's title at the same query

Tags: php, performance, download, mp3, youtube-dl

I'm currently using youtube-dl in order to download mp3 files and provide
a download of them in PHP, a basic mp3 downloading service from Youtube.
Thing is, I need the client to be able to download the mp3 file extracted
using a url given as an input and have the title of the file.

For example, for the youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUd9act5EP4
Then I would like to use this code:

```
$output = system('youtube-dl -o %(title)s mp3 --extract-audio --audio-format mp3'.$url);
```

Then I'll be able to extract both the title of the video: "MY NEW HOUSE AND MY NEW POOL" and of course save the file so I can later on read it out
to the client so he can download it.

I've tried to play with it, but I can't seem to be able to have the file's
name in the shell output while also saving file, it can only be one of them.

Problem is, saving the file as it is with that title is problematic,
I need a unique and not so obvious filename, I don't want to create 
duplicates, so I want to store the file as a unique file name, for instance -

463grshdf8hfd8hfd.mp3

But still retain the file name so instead of the user receiving a file called
463grshdf8hfd8hfd.mp3 I want him to receive a file like -

MY NEW HOUSE AND MY NEW POOL.mp3

Downloading speed is very crucial and so I want to minimize any
usage of things like file accessing and obviously the database, I want
to make it as fast as possible otherwise no client would want to use this 
service.

So how do I get both the file and its title from one shell query using youtube-dl?

Comment: Why don't get content page and use regular expression for get title and then use it in the system command for download video?

Comment: I could but that's the thing - It's dependent on internet connection, making the client wait more which is my I want to make it efficient and extract all information if possible from one action, not two.

Comment: I don't really understand that issue? You would need to download the video which takes orders of magnitude more time than just checking the title in another request? We're talking tens of seconds vs tenths of seconds here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be fairly simple to store the mp3 file under a unique name (like the video ID itself) and serve it under a different name (like the video title)